# How can I set arrays in Java?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
int setElement(int[]array) {
  int key;
  for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {

  }
  return key;
}
```

Something is wrong here.

Comment: Which output you are expected?

Comment: Your method looks more like a GET than a SET...

Comment: Ur code does not compile, does it? What is the meaning of pasting an uncompilable code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, your method needs to take `three` parameters, but your method takes just one input `array`. Also there is no need to `loop` through the `array`, `array` element can be accessed using its `index` for `insertion`, also for `retrieval`. Since the `index` is passed as `parameter` you can use it directly in your code.

All you need to do is

```
public void setValueInArray(int[] array, int index, int value){
  if(array != null && index >= 0 && index < array.length){
     array[index] = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try  to pass the index and the value you are trying to change.

```
  public void setElement(int[] array, int index, int val ) {
       if(array!=null && index >-1 && index<array.length ){
          array[index]=val ;
     }  else{
             //sorry not possible
           }
    }
```

Comment: Why is it a boolean array? I guess typing mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`key` should be passed to the method.

The way you're doing it you'll never meet the `if` condition since `key` has a garbage value - It's only declared but never defined.

Comment: +1 to help him to find the issue, rather than giving the ans blindly!

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer myArray[]= {12,23,10,22,10};
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(myArray).indexOf(23));
```

use above code

Comment: I didn't see any where you are setting the value.You are just printing the index.Misread ? Let me know If I misread :)

Comment: I meant 12,23,10.. are the values from the array `myArray[]` and `index of(23)` is 1.